# version solving failing not getting the sollution

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my `pubspec.yaml` where I have added firebase_auth and cloud_firebase:

```
name: my_khata
description: A new Flutter application.


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
```

error I am getting:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-259.16.beta.

Because my_khata requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_khata requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

please tell me the solution

Comment: try downgrading the version of plugin which is causing error

Comment: tq for your respose but i am a begginer in flutter can you please tell me which version should i download..because what i got is my current version is  >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and my project also need this version as per the error..so i am not getting which version to download @PRATIKPAWAR

Comment: you can check the previous versions of the plugins in pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
```

I think you need to check your flutter channel(Stable recommended) if above solution not working you can try any like this

```
  firebase_auth: any
  cloud_firestore: any
```

Comment: than you sir Muhammad Ashir second solution worked for me